# Omnetpp - Show Simulation Topology(Nodes, Links etc) in List/Vector

Tags: networking, omnet++, inet

I want to show simulation topology in logs. Specifically switches and connections from switches.

I add the inet/common/Topology.cc header file and i think there are multiple functions that fulfill my requirement.

But i dont understand how do i give my ned files, ini files or my modules full path to these functions ?

I have searched implementing however there is no information about that.All i can found is omnetpp manuel and this site doesn't give anything about how to use these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is documented in the `Topology.h` file. You don't have to add anything to the topology object. Modules and links register themselves with the simulation runtime. You just create a Topology object and call one of the `extractBy...()` function on it which will traverse the module hierarchy and would build the topology graph inside that Topology object. E.g. to extract ALL nodes in a network you would use `extractByPropery("networkNode")` because all network nodes are marked by the `@networkNode` property in INET. Obviuously, if you need only switches, you can use a different extract method which accepts ned types as a filter, for example.

Once you have the topology extracted, you can iterate over all nodes and dump the info. This code part is from the network configurator, wich does exactly that:

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/networklayer/configurator/ipv4/Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator.cc#L61

```
void Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator::extractTopology(cTopology& topo, NodeInfoVector& nodeInfo)
{
    // extract topology
    topo.extractByProperty("networkNode");
    EV_DEBUG << "cTopology found " << topo.getNumNodes() << " nodes\n";

    // fill in isIPNode, ift and rt members in nodeInfo[]
    nodeInfo.resize(topo.getNumNodes());
    for (int i = 0; i < topo.getNumNodes(); i++) {
        cModule *mod = topo.getNode(i)->getModule();
        nodeInfo[i].isIPNode = L3AddressResolver().findIpv4RoutingTableOf(mod) != nullptr && L3AddressResolver().findInterfaceTableOf(mod
        if (nodeInfo[i].isIPNode) {
            nodeInfo[i].ift = L3AddressResolver().interfaceTableOf(mod);
            nodeInfo[i].rt = L3AddressResolver().getIpv4RoutingTableOf(mod);
            nodeInfo[i].ipForwardEnabled = mod->hasPar("forwarding") ? mod->par("forwarding") : false;
            topo.getNode(i)->setWeight(nodeInfo[i].ipForwardEnabled ? 0.0 : INFINITY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I succeeded.